# Auto-snap window to top and bottom screen edge

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, windows-10, gnome-shell, resize

In Windows 10 currently, and Ubuntu 16.04, resizing a window by dragging its top border to the top edge of the screen causes the window's bottom border also to snap to the bottom edge of the screen.  This is quite handy.

How does one configure Ubuntu 20.04 / GNOME3 to achieve this behavior?

This isn't obvious from available GUI configuration settings (in either Settings or GNOME Tweaks), no obviously relevant extension exists, and no obvious dconf key exists, all of which, along with the loss of functionality, is surprising if not retrograde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head to Settings - Keyboard. Under the "Windows"  section, you will find options including "Maximize window horizontally" and "Maximize window vertically". Assign shortcut keys to these items to quickly arrange windows this way.

Current mouse behavior when you drag a window to the top is to fully maximize the window. Dragging left will left-tile, dragging right will right-tile. This behavior can be turned on/off in Gnome Tweaks, Window tab ("Edge tiling").

Comment: On the contrary, current mouse behavior (with Tweaks > Windows > Edge Tiling "On") on dragging a window border to the top is just to drag the window to the top; nothing else happens.  The same is true off dragging left and right.  Even if what you state were true, the question would remain, how to achieve / restore vertical maximization on dragging the top window border to the top.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut approach does achieve the effect and is good as far as it goes, but the question remains how to achieve / restore this behavior when a window's top border is dragged to the top.